# Sending json and js variable data to php script in a single ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

JAVASCRIPT: On clicking a button I want to do the following:

```
var paymentPeriodId = $('#paymentPeriodID').val();
if(paymentPeriodId < 1 ){alert('Payment period not set.');e.preventPropagation();return false; }
if(checkedRows.length < 1){alert('Supervisor not selected.');e.preventPropagation();return false; }

checkedRows = $.toJSON(checkedRows);    
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("paymentPeriodId", paymentPeriodId);
formData.append("checkedRows", checkedRows);

//    alert(JSON.stringify(checkedRows));
alert(paymentPeriodId);
alert(checkedRows);

var qurl = '<?php echo base_url();?>salary_processing/summeriseProduction';
$.ajax({
url: qurl,
type: "POST",
data:formData,
success: function(data){

        alert('successfull');
//            var data = $.parseJSON(data);
//            alert(JSON.stringify(data));

      },
});
```

PHP: This function will receive the values and will do some database operation. It is not mentioned here.

```
public function summeriseProduction() {

// Unescape the string values in the JSON array
 $supervisorIdArray = stripcslashes($this->input->post('checkedRows'));
 $paymentPeriodId = $this->input->post('paymentPeriodId');
 // Decode the JSON array
   $supervisorIdArray1 = json_decode($supervisorIdArray, TRUE);
 // $paymentPeriodId1 = json_decode($paymentPeriodId, TRUE);

 echo json_encode($supervisorIdArray1);
//    echo $paymentPeriodId;

}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/users/4476402/pekka  ,It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var formData = new FormData();
var paymentPeriodId = $('#paymentPeriodID').val();
checkedRows = $.toJSON(checkedRows);
formData.append("paymentPeriodId", paymentPeriodId);
formData.append("checkedRows", checkedRows);
var qurl = '<?php echo base_url();?>salary_processing/summeriseProduction';
$.ajax({
url: qurl,
type: "POST",    
data: formData,         
success: function(data){}
```

try like this

Comment: Do I need to use stripcslashes() and json_decode() in php function after receiving.

Comment: yes like `$checkedRows = ($_POST['checkedRows']);
$checkedRowsjson = json_decode(stripslashes($checkedRows), true);`

Comment: Thanks,  will try it.

Comment: take your time comment if something went wrong il try my best to help

Comment: I have edited the question with the formdata but not working

Comment: @HafsulMaru you so should stringify the `checkedRows` when passing in formdata pls try change `checkedRows = JSON.stringify(checkedRows);`

Comment: did this ,     checkedRows = $.toJSON(checkedRows);   
    checkedRows = JSON.stringify(checkedRows);  no response.

Comment: Hi pekka, this worked when we set     type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data:formData, in ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

```
var formData = new FormData();
var paymentPeriodId = $('#paymentPeriodID').val();
checkedRows = $.toJSON(checkedRows);
formData.append("paymentPeriodId", paymentPeriodId);
formData.append("checkedRows", checkedRows);
var qurl = '<?php echo base_url();?>salary_processing/summeriseProduction';
$.ajax({
url: qurl,
type: "POST",
processData: false,
contentType: false,
data: formData,         
success: function(data){}
```

It woks like this.